# How to apply SSO with an existing login screen and a trusted second website

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver3, openid-connect

We use IdentityServer3 (IdSvr3) for authorization/authentication. We want to offer the ability for our end user (or resource owner: RO) to log in (log through) to a second trusted website (site B) without login in to site B also, after they have already logged in to an initial website (site A). Site B administers a different set of resources for the RO. It is important that the RO is not redirected to the IdSvr3 login/consent screen. A possible approach I found so far is: inside site A an access token is created by calling RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync (passing username and password plus scope = "openid ..."). This access token is send to site B with which the RO can be authenticated. Site B retrieves the user info by calling the connect/userinfo endpoint. I want to know if this is a correct approach/flow. We assume that the RO will always enter site A first, not site B.
Thanks in advance for taking your time to think with me about this.

Comment: Request owner password flow and single sign on doesn't fit together. Please Reconsider your design. If the user doesn't need to log into site B but needs to access resources using tokens site B looks like a WebApi to me.

Comment: Thank you rawel for the answer. I was also evaluating the role and purpose of site B. Besides that, perhaps it is good idea to replace the current login page with a customized IdSvr3 login page.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do here is to send a authorize request to identity server for Site B Scope and request id_token or reference token. Make sure while sending the authorize request to idsrv you are using prompt=none, this way you will get the access_token without showing a consent to the user again if the user is already logged-in to site A.
Below example is doing the same from a JS file. In  Site A you can refer to this script file and execute the script using IIFE.

```
 function getIdentityServerURL() {
    var url = global.appSettings.identityServerURL
                        + "/connect/authorize?client_id=siteB&response_type=id_token token&redirect_uri="
                        + global.appSettings.siteBUrl + "/Main/SsoCallback&scope=siteBscope openid email roles&prompt=none&nonce="
                        + genNonce();
    return encodeURI(url);
}
```

The code above will redirect you to SsoCallback page where you can create a virtual iframe and post the token back to site B after reducing the result from authorize request. Refer to code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var identityresult = window.location.hash.split('&').reduce(function (result, item) {
    var parts = item.split('=');
    result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    return result;
}, {});

window.parent.postMessage(identityresult, '*');
```

your script can listen to postmessage event. Hope this helps.